# class is not matching up to json string

Tags: c#, vb.net, json, json.net

I have jquery looping through a html table and putting it into an object then using `JSON.stringify` to convert that javascript object to json , see json below

```
{
"0":{"name":"fdgd","surname":"ssdt"},
"1":{"name":"fdsf","surname":"vn"},
"2":{"name":"dfsb","surname":"mry"},
"3":{"name":"hsdsdfry","surname":"smh"}
}
```

My issue is with JSON.net and the CLASSs im am trying to match up for it to convert the json into my `tableT` object

After it does the `Jsonconvert` I get  empty objects, can you please tell me what is wrong with my classs. Im using vb.net and .net 2. So I guess my question is how do I match my tableT class up to my json string? Thank you for the help.

```
Dim tableOBJ As tableT = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of tableT)(myJSON)


Public Class tableT

    Private _allRows As List(Of Rows)

    Property AllRows As List(Of Rows)
        Get
            Return _allRows
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Rows))
            _allRows = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class Rows

    Private _name As String
    Private _surname As String

    Property name As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Property surname As String
        Get
            Return _surname
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _surname = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing it, it appears that

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of tableT)(myJSON)
```

should really be something more like

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Rows))(myJSON)
```

since there isn't any way for JsonConvert to know that you want the rows in the AllRows object.

So, your code would look more like:

```
Dim tableOBJ As New tableT 
tableOBJ.AllRows = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Rows))(myJSON)
```

** EDIT **

After testing this, I was only able to get this to work by modifying the Json string to look more like what I understand a Json array should look like.

Specifically, if I changed the array to look like:

```
{"AllRows": [
{"name":"fdgd","surname":"ssdt"},
{"name":"fdsf","surname":"vn"},
{"name":"dfsb","surname":"mry"},
{"name":"hsdsdfry","surname":"smh"}
]}
```

Then your original code works correctly.

What your original Json is doing is expecting that there are properties in the class called 0, 1, 2, and 3 of type Rows, which is not possible with VB and is, I am certain, not what you are looking to accomplish.

You can verify this by adding properties for Zero, One, Two, and Three of type Rows to your tableT:

```
Public Class tableT

    Public Zero As New Rows
    Public One As New Rows
    Public Two As New Rows
    Public Three As New Rows
```

changing your json to:

```
{
"Zero":{"name":"fdgd","surname":"ssdt"},
"One":{"name":"fdsf","surname":"vn"},
"Two":{"name":"dfsb","surname":"mry"},
"Three":{"name":"hsdsdfry","surname":"smh"}
}
```

and deserializing using your original class. You will see then that the new properties are populated with the contents of your json string.

Comment: can I send you my test project? please? thank you for the help

Comment: Cannot deserialize current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Rows]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '0', line 1, position 5.